# How to apply Bootstrap style to email body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My .net MVC application has logic to send emails to clients , below is the code which sends email .

```
  string strBody = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><title>Ticket Application</title><meta charset='utf-8' /><script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'></head><body><div class='container'><div class='row'><table class='table-condensed table-responsive'><thead><tr><th></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class='danger'><td><label>Title</label></td><td>{title}</td></tr><tr class='active'><td><label>Description</label></td><td>{description}</td></tr><tr><td><label>Project</label></td><td>{project}</td></tr><tr><td><label>Priorty</label></td><td>{priorty}</td></tr><tr><td><label>Current Status</label></td><td>{Open}</td></tr></tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table></div></div></body></html>';";

string strToAddress = "test@test.com";

using (SmtpClient client = new   SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHost"],    Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"])))
{
MailMessage message = new    MailMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPFromUser"],
                                                  strToAddress,
                                                    //ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSubject"],
                                                  "Test Subject",
                                                  strBody);
message.IsBodyHtml = true;              
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new             NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPassowrd"]);
client.Send(message);message.Dispose();
client.Dispose();

}
```

"strBody" variable contains the HTML which is the body of the mail.
In this HTML I have included CDN for Bootstrap css and JS files.
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js

But I don't see bootstrap styles applied to the email content.
Please let me know what needs to be done so that bootstrap styles get applied to email content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only inline CSS styles work in case of HTML in emails.